# Importing unnecessary files to a java program will increase the size of the byte code.

Tags: java

Importing unnecessary files to a java program will increase the size of the byte
code, Is this true?

Comment: Compile the code and see for yourself.

Comment: It's not possible to determine which imports where used from the compiled code, so this statement wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true. The Import command is for the compiler only. It does not impact the compiler output in any way.